# SSH/SFTP Reverse Proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, sftp

I have two machines accessible on the Internet with no NAT involved. Both machines run an SSH service.

I want to connect via SSH/SFTP to Server A on Port 2000 and this connection should be routed to Server B Port 22 (behavior like a HTTP reverse proxy but using SSH/SFTP instead of HTTP)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like an iptables rule on "Reverse Proxy" server allowing connections to RS through it using sftp without first having to log into RP?

Comment: Yes, but I am not shure if it works with iptables?

Comment: Which one is *server A* and *server B* ? If *server A* is *Reverse Proxy*, my first answer could do the job.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Its just routing packets. You cannot reverse-proxy encrypted tunnels anyway, I think he means routing, because otherwise, all routers could generically be termed "Proxies". If you opened a port on RP, enabled routing in the kernel, translated that request to a NAT masqueraded request to RS, and ensured that RS could reply to RP, it should work fine. Really depends on what OS is running on RP, I'm guessing linux, but you don't specify.

Comment: Possible solution: http://serverfault.com/a/387231/35383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ssh port forward to achieve this

```
ssh -L localportinmypc:hostname_of_the_behind_the_firewall:remoteport hostname_of_my_firewall
```

Then connect to local tunnel port:

```
sftp -o Port=localportinmyp localhost
```

or

```
ssh -p localportinmyp
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be no problem with iptables:

```
#!/bin/bash
export IP="1.2.3.4"
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables \-t nat \-A POSTROUTING \-o eth0 \-d $IP \-j MASQUERADE
iptables \-A PREROUTING \-t nat \-p tcp \--dport 2000 \-j DNAT \--to $IP:22
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -e none userA@serverA:2000 nc -w 1 serverB 22" userB@ServerB
```

where you connect to *serverA* with ssh login *userA* for opening a *forward* connection to *serverB* to wich you log in with *userB*.

**Explanation:**

The proxy command open a ssh connection to *ServerA* (with username *userA*) and initiate a bidirectional connection to port 22 of *serverB*.

The initial `ssh` command use this `ProxyCommand` to establish a bidirectional connection to *ServerB* where you have to log in with *userB*.

In fine:

There is a crypted connection from Laptop to ServerA (step 1 in your drawing) and

another crypted connection from Laptop to ServerB (step 1 + step 2), encapsulated in first connection in his first part (step 1), than binded by `nc` in the second part (step2).

Instead of HTTP, As `SSH` is bidirectional, when a connection is open, all requests and answers follow the same connection. So there is no need to think about your step 3 and 4.

Comment: I added a picture of a reverse proxy setup